# Packaging python application as a zip including all dependencies in the sub-directories

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a python application using paramkio libraries. I use the pycharm for development. In my case, I have pip-installed the paramiko libraries in my virutal environment so my application could use it. However, I have to deploy this in an application server with no connectivity to internet and the paramiko library is also not available in the local repos. 
I tried to add the following to the setup.py:

```
 from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='appname',
    version='',
    packages=['MyTestPackage'],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='myname',
    author_email='',
    description='', **requires=['paramiko'],**
)
```

I try to build this using the sdist but I cannot find the paramiko libraries in the sub directory.

I come from java background, so when I package jars, I can usually build them into a bundle using dependency management tools like graddle or maven, and distribute them as an application.

However, with python I do not seem to be able to do so, other than probably creating an RPM. 
Can someone help on what needs to be done in order to package my application as a complete bundle(so I do not have to depend on client to have the libraries in their repos)? 
Note. I use python 2.7.14

Comment: Have you looked at py2exe?  It is old, but works.  There are other similar packaging solutions, but this is the one I use.

Comment: Had a brief look at py2exe and it seems to work for windows. But is there an alternative in linux(more importantly cross platform?)

Comment: Anyone who has any inputs on this question?